# Check if observable is complete

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to authorize user to view certain router path.

```
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
return this.userService.isAdmin() || this.userService.isEmployee()
}
```

UserService methods are synchronous. UserService is singleton which loads user data from backend. This is not problem when user go through normal flow of application. But when user tries to go directly into guarded path path UserService info may not be loaded in time which results in error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleId' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'roleId' of undefined
```

This is UserService code

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  public $user;
  public loggedUser;

  constructor(private loginService: ResourceLoginService) {
    this.$user = this.loginService.get().$observable;
    this.$user.subscribe(response => {
      this.loggedUser = response;
    });
  }

  isAdmin(): boolean {
    return this.loggedUser.roleId === 1;
  }
```

I basically want to subscribe to $user and call methods async if it didn't complete yet or call methods if it has finished in CanActive guard. What is correct way to approach this?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove subscription for `user$` and write:

```
  isAdmin(): boolean {
    return this.user$
      .map(user => user.roleId === 1);
  }
```

For `canActivate` you can return: `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean`, it will wait for Promise/Observable before it resolves route permissions.

Comment: Yes, this solves the problem for directly accessing the route ($user is still getting json from BE), but in case $user already has completed, it returns observable that is complete( if I understand this correctly, nevertheless it doesn't work if $user completed in the past)

Answer (score 0):

Solution is that function should return consistent type, no matter the case. If one of case is synchronous and another asynchronous function needs to return async observable from synchronous source.

```
export class UserService {
  public $user;
  public loggedUser;

  constructor(private loginService: ResourceLoginService) {
    this.$user = this.loginService.get().$observable;
    this.$user.subscribe(response => this.loggedUser = response);
  }

  isAdmin(): Observable<boolean> {
    if (this.loggedUser) {
      return Observable.of(this.loggedUser.roleId === 1);
    } else
      return this.$user
        .map(user => user.roleId === 1);
  }
```